# Is there a better way to obtain the geometry of image in Carrierwave than hacking through manipulate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

The current way I'm doing this is like this:

```
  def avatar_geometry

    width = 0
    height = 0
    self.avatar.manipulate! do |img|
      # this is kind of a hack, we're actually not manipulating anything here, we just
      # need access to imagemagick

      @width = img[:width]
      @height = img[:height]
      img
    end

    {:height => @height, :width => @width}
  end
```

We all know that manipulate is not used for this kind of purpose, I have tried hours trying to open the file through MiniMagick directly but it's stored in GridFS and I could not find a way to open it directly, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this metadata plug-in?
https://github.com/gzigzigzeo/carrierwave-meta